# How to use .pack() method correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi guys i'm buolding a simple calculator and having trouble with the `.pack()` method for placing the buttons, i want to place the "4" number in the `bottone5` variable right under the "7" number, the `bottone1` variable.I know that pack use all the left space available, but how to place "4" under the "7" number with .pack() ?? Thanks, image and code for reference

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
foto_cestino = PhotoImage(file="cestino2.png")
foto_cancella = PhotoImage(file="daidaidao.png")
window.call('wm', 'iconphoto', window._w, PhotoImage(file="opopo.png"))
window.title("Calcolatrice")
window.geometry("670x355")
equation_text = ""
equation_lable = StringVar()
label = Label(window, textvariable=equation_lable, font=('Ink Free',20), bg="#01335A", fg="white", width=44, height=2)
label.pack()
bottone1 = Button(window, text="7", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("7"))
bottone1.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone1.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW,padx=(2,0))
bottone2 = Button(window, text="8", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("8"))
bottone2.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone2.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW)
bottone3 = Button(window, text="9", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("9"))
bottone3.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone3.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW)
bottone4 = Button(window, text="+", font=('Ink Free',20), width=3, height=1, bg="#FF9D12",command=lambda: operazioni("+"))
bottone4.configure(activebackground="#e87400")
bottone4.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW)
bottone20 = Button(window, text="x²", font=('Ink Free',20), width=3, height=1, bg="#FF9D12",command=lambda: button_press("^"))
bottone20.configure(activebackground="#e87400")
bottone20.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW)
bottone5 = Button(window, text="4", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("4"))
bottone5.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone5.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: For a calculator, `grid` seems much more appropriate than `pack`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi, i know how to use grid but i want to do it with pack in order to use always the same method (pack), is possible with pack?

Comment: You cannot with pack. The grid is easier to layout.

Comment: You can nest containers; use one for the keypad and use `grid` for that, and put that into another together with the display, using `pack`.

Answer (score 1):

use `grid()` function, `grid()` is based on rows and columns, so it is better in your case,

a full guide:

https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/

btw I made it work easily without `label` part

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
foto_cestino = PhotoImage(file="cestino2.png")
foto_cancella = PhotoImage(file="daidaidao.png")
window.call('wm', 'iconphoto', window._w, PhotoImage(file="opopo.png"))
window.title("Calcolatrice")
window.geometry("670x355")
equation_text = ""
equation_lable = StringVar()
bottone1 = Button(window, text="7", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("7"))
bottone1.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone1.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=W)
bottone2 = Button(window, text="8", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("8"))
bottone2.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone2.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=W)
bottone3 = Button(window, text="9", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("9"))
bottone3.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone3.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky=W)
bottone4 = Button(window, text="+", font=('Ink Free',20), width=3, height=1, bg="#FF9D12",command=lambda: operazioni("+"))
bottone4.configure(activebackground="#e87400")
bottone4.grid(column=3,row=1,sticky=W)
bottone20 = Button(window, text="x²", font=('Ink Free',20), width=3, height=1, bg="#FF9D12",command=lambda: button_press("^"))
bottone20.configure(activebackground="#e87400")
bottone20.grid(column=4,row=1,sticky=W)
bottone5 = Button(window, text="4", font=('Ink Free',20), width=5, height=1, bg="#008BC7",command=lambda: button_press("4"))
bottone5.configure(activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone5.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky=W)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks for the answer, but it gives me problem in on other part in the code that i diidn't wrote, when i pack a scrollbar in the right with "scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)" and gives me error because the space is already used with pack, see why i want to use only the pack method because the are in conflict

Comment: you dont use pack() if you are using grid(), you can only use one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are organizing widgets in rows and columns, `grid` is a much better choice than `pack`, since `grid` is specifically designed to manage rows and columns. I strongly encourage you to use `grid`.

However, based on some of the comments, it appears you do not want to use `grid`. In order to use `pack` you're going to have to create some additional widgets. Specifically, you'll need to use one frame either for every row, or for every column. The downside to this is that you'll need to explicitly make each button the same size so that they line up properly.

Here is a simplified example:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

row1 = Frame(window)
row2 = Frame(window)

row1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
row2.pack(side="top", fill="x")

buttone1 = Button(row1, text="7", width=1)
buttone2 = Button(row1, text="8", width=1)
buttone3 = Button(row1, text="9", width=1)
buttone4 = Button(row1, text="+", width=1)
buttone20 = Button(row1, text="x²", width=1)

buttone5 = Button(row2, text="4", width=1)

buttone1.pack(side="left")
buttone2.pack(side="left")
buttone3.pack(side="left")
buttone4.pack(side="left")
buttone20.pack(side="left")

buttone5.pack(side="left")

window.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Use place() function to place the buttone5 under just button 7 or else Follow this [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/SYrjAUFqPZU)

Comment: Hi, i know how to use place but i want to do it with pack, is possible with pack?

Comment: pack() not do this. pack() function pack the text or button and just put it in the window. changing place of text or button is can be done by place() only. pack() function only do one think, it just pack and put to window.